# How to get access to response in koa.js

Tags: node.js, chat, backend, long-polling, koa

I want to rewrite a long-polling chat (like [here](https://github.com/mixartemev/nodejs-long-polling-chat)) using koa.js. But I've faced a problem:

```
const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router.get('/', homePage)
.get('/subscribe', subscribe)
.post('/publish', publish)

app
.use(router.routes())
.listen(3000);
```

I can't access to ctx.response in next part of code. I need this to push the object to clients' array, and then, to call response.end() in 'publish' method ([node js version](https://github.com/mixartemev/nodejs-long-polling-chat/blob/master/chat.js))

```
subscribe = (ctx, next) => {
  clients.push(ctx.res);
  ctx.res.on('close', () => {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(response), 1);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Koa middlewares (and routes) work with promises. If the promise resolves, the route is considered 'done' and the response is sent to the client.

If you didn't return a promise (or used an async function) the middleware is considered to execute and end immediately. When you call `ctx.res.end()` it's basically too late.

So how do you tell koa to not automatically end the request? You can do this by sending a promise that resolves later.

Here's an example of a middleware that sends back a promise that never resolves:

```
const myMw = ctx => {
  return new Promise( () => {});
}
```

Given that you're migrating from express to koa (great choice!) you shouldn't try to exactly adopt the exact same patterns from express. Long-polling is really well suited for a promise-first solution.

I would highly recommend you use promises for everything. If a client 'publishes' a message to every other client, it should result in a bunch of promises resolving.